# C++ Qualification conversions - constness

Tags: c++

Can someone explain why the second conversion is allowed while the first one is not? They both potentially allow the modification of a const lvalue...

```
double *wPtr;
const double ** wRef = &wPtr;
const double * const * wRef = &wPtr;
```

Thank you,
regu

Adding compile error from Comeau...

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    double *wPtr;
    const double ** wRef = &wPtr;
    return 0;
}

Compiling Comeau C/C++ 4.3.10.1 (Oct  6 2008 11:28:09) for ONLINE_EVALUATION_BETA2
Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing.  All rights reserved.
MODE:strict errors C++ C++0x_extensions

"ComeauTest.c", line 4: error: a value of type "double **" cannot be used to
      initialize an entity of type "const double **"
  const double ** wRef = &wPtr;
                         ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "ComeauTest.c".
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the error message you get when compiling this code? I think something else may be going on...

Comment: @antonm: No, he's right in that the first one constitutes a clear and compiler-caught error, and the second does not. He just doesn't have the implication of the second one quite right.

Comment: @Nicholas: yes, I see it now. Someone (you?) had an answer posted that I can't see anymore. It had this useful link: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17

Comment: @antonm: I deleted it while I corrected it. I just woke up and got the explanation messed up. :) It's back now.

Comment: That link isn't working any more so here it is again: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion

Answer (score 2):

Because the second example does *not* allow the modification of a const lvalue (at least not without actual effort on your part (casting, which is itself often a sign of danger)). I'm not sure why you think it does, as you provide no further explanation..

```
const double * const * wRef = &wPtr;
```

You have to read this very carefully. It says "wRef is a pointer to a const pointer to a double which is const".

You can modify wRef (to point to a different object). You cannot modify the value it points to (the wPtr pointer) nor can you modify the value that wPtr points to. This does not provide an (ordinary) avenue to modifying a const lvalue.

The first example is, of course, clearly dangerous and disallowed as you expect.

Incidentally, you should read through the [Const correctness chapter of the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) if you haven't already. Section 17 goes through this specific case, though primarily from the angle of why the first isn't allowed, and doesn't explicitly try to describe why the second is allowed.

Comment: Thank you, your answer and the c++ faq link cleared things up. I was looking at the problem from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

So having the word 'const' to the left of a word is rather misleading.

Your second statement would be better stated as `double const * *wRef = &wPtr`
Basically, this is a pointer to a pointer to a const double. You can modify the lvalue here, because it's *not* const - only the double being pointed to is const.

The second is `double const * const * wRef` - i.e. pointer to constant pointer to constant double.
The pointer-to-pointer itself can be changed, but the double it then points to must be const. You can't them modify the const lvalue.